# Is it okay to use VirtualBox on the “personal license” in a small company on a small number of computers?

Tags: virtualbox, license

Does this excerpt from the official [VirtualBox FAQ](https://web.archive.org/web/20100204053823/https://www.virtualbox.org/wiki/Licensing_FAQ) mean it is totally okay to use VirtualBox at my company on a small number of computers?

> It doesn't matter whether you just use it for fun or run your multi-million euro business with it. Also, if you install it on your work PC at some large company, this is still personal use. However, if you are an administrator and want to deploy it to the 500 desktops in your company, this would no longer qualify as personal use. (http://www.virtualbox.org/wiki/Licensing_FAQ)

Comment: IMO they deserve the money, and it's not really -that- much.

Comment: Disagree, they do not deserve the money

Answer (score 8):

I think it's summarized pretty succinctly in "§ 2 Grant of license':

“Personal Use” requires that you use the Product on the same Host Computer where you installed it yourself and that no more than one client connect to that Host Computer at a time for the purpose of displaying Guest Computers remotely.

Answer (score 3):

As of **October 2018**, the situation is the following:

- Standard VB builds downloaded from virtualbox.org are now GPL2 (i.e. **completely free** to use in any way)
- The Extension Pack ("Oracle VM VirtualBox Extension Pack") is available under the PUEL (i.e. non-commercial and single-user, or 30 day evaluation).
- The Extension Pack is also available for commercial use from the Oracle Store, licensed either per-socket ($$$) or per-user with a minimum of 100 users ($,$$$).

The Extension pack includes the following features - if you don't need them, there is no point in paying:

- Virtual USB 2.0 (EHCI) and 3.0 (xHCI) devices
- VirtualBox Remote Desktop Protocol (VRDP) support (to connect to the VB control panel via RDP)
- Host webcam passthrough
- Intel PXE boot ROM.
- Experimental support for PCI passthrough on Linux hosts.
- Disk image encryption with AES

Comment: As an addition to this: It is also possible for a large company to make a special deal with Oracle. E.g. if you are a big Oracle customer (like databases) they might throw in the VirtualBox licenses for free. And some companies provide man-power to VirtualBox development (especially in those area's of the software that lack features or stability for their own use of VB) in exchange for the licenses.

Comment: I still wish they had a "laptop" price for SME customers, in the two-digits... even one socket is quite dear.

Comment: Oh yes. Oracle and their pricing-model. We wouldn't wan't Larry not to be able to buy a new super-yacht every year, now would we ?

Answer (score 2):

As I read it, no you need a license.  It is not the numbers, it is that you are using it for corporate use.  The 500 is just an example; the key is that you are using it for non-evaluation purposes in a business.

See the [full license](http://www.virtualbox.org/wiki/VirtualBox_PUEL).  The summary is:

> In summary, the VirtualBox PUEL allows
>   you to use VirtualBox free of charge
>
> ```
> * for personal use or, alternatively,
> * for product evaluation.
> ```
>
> In addition, academic use of
>   VirtualBox is also permitted free of
>   charge by the PUEL.
>
> If you do not belong to either
>   category, you will have to purchase a
>   commercial license. Do not hesitate to
>   contact Sun Microsystems, Inc. in this
>   matter.

This only covers the full package.  If you only need the features in the VirtualBox Open Source Edition (OSE) edition that is under the GPL and does not require a license for corporate use.

If you are really looking for something free you do have a number of other options:  [VMWare Server](http://www.vmware.com/products/server/), [VMWare ESXi](http://www.vmware.com/products/esxi/), [Microsoft Virtual PC 2007](http://www.microsoft.com/windows/virtual-pc/support/virtual-pc-2007.aspx), [Windows Virtual Machine](http://www.microsoft.com/windows/virtual-pc/default.aspx).

Comment: I only need the features in the Virtualbox OSE so I guess there's no need to buy a license, right?

Comment: From http://www.virtualbox.org/wiki/Downloads  "The VirtualBox OSE sources are available free of charge under the terms and conditions of the GNU General Public License, Version 2. By downloading from the below links, you agree to these terms and conditions."

Comment: ...so I have to download the source code and build Virtualbox for myself for the terms and conditions to apply?

Comment: Yes or find some one to build them for you.  There is a project that offers Windows builds: http://sourceforge.net/projects/vboxwin32/